# How Java know which method should be override when use lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

With JAVA8, inner class can be replaced with lambda expression.

```
Comparator c = (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());

Runnable java8Runner = () ->{System.out.println("I am running");};
```

How jvm know, this lambda should override the right method? In above examples, they are `run()` and `compare()`.

Comment: Your first example won't compile, because the use of a *raw* `Comparator` means that the compiler has no idea what the type of `a` and `b` is. Changing it to something like `Comparator<String>` will make it compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thilo is right.

Nevertheless, the term

> Single-Method-Interfaces

is not the more appropriate because a functional interface may have multiple methods : potentially multiple default methods but one and single abstract method.
For example it is a valid functional interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyInterface {

    Integer getResult();
    default boolean isNoResult(){
       return getResult()==null;
    }
}
```

An expression lambda can be used only in the context of a functional interface.
A functional interface is a Java interface specifying one and single abstract method. 
In your example, Comparator and Runnable have only one abstract method.
More details here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

> How jvm know, this lambda should override the right method? In above
>   examples, they are run() and compare().

If you use a lambda expression with a no functional interface, the compilation wil be in error : the compiler will indeed complain about it  with the explicit message : 
**The target type of this expression must be a functional interface**

So, even if it is not mandatory, if you create a interface in the aim being a functional interface, it is a good practice to declare it with the annotation `@FunctionalInterface` to enforce the compiler to check it is a valid functional interface : one and single abstract method. In this way, you would know right now when your interface is a functional interface valid or not. 
That's why JDK classes in Java 8 does it.

Comment: Even this is not the full picture; a functional interface has exactly one `abstract` method that does not match a method in `java.lang.Object`. This is the reason why `Comparator` is a functional interface despite having two `abstract` methods, `boolean equals(Object)` matches a method declared in `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: You are right to precise that methods of the Object class are not considered by functional interfaces

Answer (score 7):

This is facilitated by means of Single-Method-Interfaces. There is only a single (abstract) method in these interfaces. If there is ambiguity, the shorthand lambda syntax cannot be used.

You can use the [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation to have the compiler enforce this for an interface (but it is not necessary, the interface can be used in lambdas even without it).